# sequence to clear config cache on SharePoint servers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, administration

We have 2 app servers and 2 WFE`s. What should be the ideal sequence to clear the config cache on SharePoint servers and why we should follow that sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific order that needs to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific order for clearing the config cache on servers, you can start from wfe then app servers or reverse order.

As it build the cache on the server where u performing the operation so no impact to other servers.